# Multiple property file

Tags: spring

How to handle multiple property files in spring with placeholderconfigurer?

I have an application context in Common project with following bean entry:

`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location" value="classpath:database.properties" />
</bean>`

And in Service layer project I have another application context file with this bean entry:

`<beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

<beans:property name="location" value="classpath:kestrel.properties" />

</beans:bean>`

The entries in property file are like :
database proprties:
URL= xxx
USERNAME = xxx
PWD = xxx

kestrel.properties:
mediacast.url = xxx

With these setting, when I start my tomcat server I get expection like:
Could not resolve placeholder 'mediacast.url' from kestrel.properties - property file.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

On my application, I do that:

```
<bean id="envPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>one/path/to/file</value>
            <value>another/path/to/file</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: When I use this I get : Could not resolve placeholder 'xxx.xxx' from one of the property files. so it is not able to resolve the place holders from second property file.

Comment: @Jiten Could you edit your question and add the example of your Spring configuration?